# java.net.Proxy problema com Marshmallow e versões abaixo

Tags: java, android, proxy

Tenho o seguinte teste :

```
package com.technopartner.technosdk.proxy;


import android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Authenticator;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.PasswordAuthentication;
import java.net.Proxy;
import java.net.ProxySelector;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketAddress;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;

import static junit.framework.Assert.assertTrue;

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class OkHttpClientTest {

    private static int PORT = 1080;
    private static  String[] IPS = {"127.0.0.10", "127.0.0.11","127.0.0.12"};
    private static String USER_NAME = "USUARIO";
    private static String PASSWORD = "SENHA";
    private static String URL_CONNECT = "https://www.google.com/";

    private final Authenticator authenticator = new Authenticator() {
        @Override
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(USER_NAME, PASSWORD.toCharArray());
        }
    };

    @Test
    public void testSocksFunctionality() throws IOException {

        // set Authenticator
        Authenticator.setDefault(authenticator);

        // Create socket...
        final Socket socket = new Socket(IPS[0], PORT);
        assertTrue(socket.isConnected());

        //create URL...
        final URL url = new URL(URL_CONNECT);
        InetSocketAddress  socketAddress = new InetSocketAddress(IPS[0], PORT);
        // create Proxy
        final Proxy proxy = new Proxy( Proxy.Type.SOCKS, socketAddress );

        // Open connection...
        final URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection(proxy);
        urlConnection.connect();

        assertTrue( urlConnection.getDoInput() );

        final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .proxy(proxy)
                .retryOnConnectionFailure(false)
                .build();

        final Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(URL_CONNECT)
                .build();

        assertTrue(client.newCall(request).execute().isSuccessful());
    }

}
```

Este realiza o teste de conexão utilizando um Proxy.

Quando executo o teste em API's abaixo da 24, ocorre o seguinte erro:

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: Host is unresolved: www.google.com
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:865)
at okhttp3.internal.platform.AndroidPlatform.connectSocket(AndroidPlatform.java:63)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:223)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:149)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:192)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:121)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:100)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
```

Como faço para realizar conexões utilizando Proxy em versões abaixo da API 24 ?

Answer (score 0):

A princípio as versões abaixo da API 24 não é para influenciar nesse tipo de conexão.

No entanto, se você estiver utilizando exatamente a API 24 ou acima, é possível que esteja com problemas de segurança como certificados por exemplo; sendo assim pode ser necessário fazer algumas configurações.

Se este for o caso, recomendo a leitura deste guia do Android Developers:

[Configurações de segurança de rede](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config)

Voltando para a pergunta, tente modificar seu código para algo nesse modelo:

```
int proxyPort = 8080;
String proxyHost = "proxyHost";
final String username = "username";
final String password = "password";

Authenticator proxyAuthenticator = new Authenticator() {
  @Override public Request authenticate(Route route, Response response) throws IOException {
       String credential = Credentials.basic(username, password);
       return response.request().newBuilder()
           .header("Proxy-Authorization", credential)
           .build();
  }
};

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .proxy(new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(proxyHost, proxyPort)))
    .proxyAuthenticator(proxyAuthenticator)
    .build();
```

Verifique também se o seu arquivo `Manifest` possui a permissão:  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

Fonte: [OkHTTPClient Proxy authentication how to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35554380/okhttpclient-proxy-authentication-how-to)